# Rails/React routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm working on the following Rails/React [app](https://github.com/fervisa/accounts-react-rails).

When I root the app to `records#index`, the react app wouldn't let me submit a new item into the table, and I'm getting the following error from the server log:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/")`.

But when I go to `localhost:3000/records` the app *would* let me submit a new item with no issues.

Why is that?

Comment: Please show relevant code (not the entire repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you're hitting your root path ("/") with a POST request when "/" is only defined for GET requests. Using `localhost:3000/records` probably works because you have something like `resources :records` defined in your routes, which creates a `POST` action at the `/records` path.

To fix, ensure you're only sending "GET" requests to the root path. Create actions via POST should probably go to the `/records` route.